# Migration from Oracle 10gR2 to Oracle XE

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, migration, oraclexe

One of my application currently uses Oracle 10gR2 as the backend, with PL/SQL Stored Procedures, Triggers, Sequences, etc.

I want to migrate to [**Oracle XE**](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html). Can this edition serve as the primary database for a server?

Also, i am unclear, about is there any limit on:

- Size of database, in terms of no. of records or memory size?
- no. of concurrent connections?
- CPU/other resource utilisation limits/impact?

Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Xpress Edition has several limitations, including:

- A physical limit of 4GB for storage,
- A limit of 1GB or RAM. Even if your server has more, it won't be used.
- A limit of 1Cpu (or 1 core?). Even if your server has more, it won't be used.
- No support from Oracle. You'll have to rely on good samaritan if you encounter any problem.

The details are on [Oracle Website](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html).

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing to XE, even though i mentioned Lite. I gather now that Lite can not serve as a stand alone product.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Benoit is pointing you in the right direction with Oracle XE. [Oracle Lite](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/lite/index.html) is a separate product meant for mobile devices. I can't see circumstances where you would switch from a full Oracle 10g to Oracle Lite

Comment: I didn't even know about the product for mobile devices..